# ANSI C - Benefit of assigning alternative name to pointer type using typedef

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the right way to typedef a type and the same type's pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465976/what-is-the-right-way-to-typedef-a-type-and-the-same-types-pointer)

I've recently been using Libxml2 in my project and noticed it uses typedefs like the following:

```
typedef struct _xmlNode xmlNode
typedef xmlNode * xmlNodePtr
```

The benefit of the first typedef is obvious.  However I'm not sure why you'd assign an alternative name to xmlNode *.  To me it's more explicit and readable to use **xmlNode *** than to use **xmlNodePtr** but I might be missing something.

What problems would this typedef solve and also what benefits would it bring?

Comment: It is a matter of taste. I agree with your position (I hate `xmlNodePtr`-like `typedef`-s for pointers). And GTk don't use that (even if GCC internals has a typedef `tree` and another typedef `gimple` for pointers to complex data types).

Comment: These kinds of typedefs are not particularaly useful.  But one case where pointer typedefs are really useful is for function pointers, because raw function pointer syntax is nasty to look at.

Comment: FWIW, here is the opinion of the Linux kernel developers along with some rationale: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What problems would this typedef solve and also what benefits would it bring?

My opinion is typedefing object pointers is bad and should not be done.

First it alters the grammar of the C language by hiding that the declared object is of a pointer type.

Second type qualifiers (`const` and `volatile`) cannot penetrate a typedef.

If we take your example:

```
typedef struct _xmlNode xmlNode;
typedef xmlNode * xmlNodePtr;
```

It is now impossible to declare an object so the pointee is `const` using `xmlNodePtr` alias.

```
const xmlNodePtr xp;
```

means `xp` is `const` not `*xp`.

```
const xmlNode x = /* ... */;
const xmlNodePtr xp = &x;  // Error!
```

By the way in the Linux kernel coding style they also recommend not to use `typedef` for pointers:

> "It's a *mistake* to use typedef for structures and pointers."

Comment: If the type is opaque, you can't modify the data through the value, so the inability for `const` to penetrate the typedef isn't critical in the client code.  It may be a more serious problem in the implementation of the class itself.  (I still generally prefer not to use typedefs of non-function pointer types.)

Comment: Note that if you take the kernel coding style then `typedef struct _xmlNode xmlNode;` is just as bad as `typedef xmlNode * xmlNodePtr;`. Well, maybe not equally bad, but equally forbidden. This will probably surprise and upset the kind of C programmer who was thinking of typedefing a pointer, and cause them to throw out the advice of the kernel coding style entirely ;-)

Answer (score 2):

C APIs often provide *opaque handles*, which discourage the consumer from asking what they are and attempting to poke inside. The fact that these handles are pointers is immaterial and should not matter to the consumer, nor should she be burdened with the lexical clutter of an extra star.

For example, it's perfectly possible to write a C++ binding by defining a handle:

```
typedef void * MyHandle;
```

Now we give the blissful C consumer some functions:

```
MyHandle create_gizmo();
void destroy_gizmo(MyHandle);
int do_magic(MyHandle, int, int);
```

Simple as that. The user immediately sees how to use it:

```
#include "MagicAPI.h"

MyHandle h = create_gizmo();

submit_result(do_magic(h, 12, 91));

destroy_gizmo(h);
```

And the C++ library developer simply unwraps the handle and populates the API functions (which are of course declared `extern "C"`):

```
#include "MagicAPI.h"
#include "SuperGizmo.hpp"

MyHandle create_gizmo() { return static_cast<MyHandle>(new SuperGizmo); }

void destroy_gizmo(MyHandle h) { delete static_cast<SuperGizmo *>(h); }

int do_magic(MyHandle h, int a, int b)
{
    return static_cast<SuperGizmo *>(h)->foo(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Using `typedef void *MyHandle` can lead to misuse of the function in a way that `typedef struct MyStruct *MyHandle` won't.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: that's true, but it makes the C and C++ interop a bit more questionable, doesn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure why it affects C and C++ interoperability.  AFAIK, you can forward declare in C++ the same as you can in C, AFAIK (modulo namespaces, but that's tangential to the issue at hand).  I did use separate names for `struct MyStruct` and `MyHandle`...because `typedef struct MyHandle *MyHandle;` would be abhorrent to me, and would probably cause schizophrenia in a C++ compiler.

Comment: The bigger problem with `typedef void *MyHandle;` is that a variable of type `typedef void *YourHandle;` can be passed to a function that expects a `MyHandle` and the compiler can do nothing to warn you of the problem.  You might as well throw away the type-safety provided by prototypes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: how then would you call the type that's used in the C++ code? I can't think of a portable, standard-condoned way of naming it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem.  You can write `typedef struct Something *SomeHandle;` in C++.  You can then (in the code that needs to know about the internals) write `class Something { ... };`, can't you?  And not using `void *` also avoids having to do casts on the parameters to functions.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Well, is there any guarantee that the pointer type `Something*` in C++ and the unrelated `struct Something *` in C will actually be binarily compatible? It seems plausible on the face of it, but I can't prove it. For example, it could be that the conversion `Something* -> void*` in C++ could add an offset or so, and in C there could be a different offset.

Comment: I'm not sure; I don't do enough C and C++ interworking to have relevant experience — I primarily work in C. When I've needed to do it, I've not run into problems, but I've never gone anywhere near pushing the limits (multiple inheritance, virtuals, etc did not enter into the equation). I'll leave it to others to persuade us.  I think the loss of type safety with 'everything is a void pointer' is serious; if you've ever worked on a system where half the parameters to the functions are void pointers to multiple different structures, then you'd know the pain. Having to write casts in GDB? Ugh!

Comment: Note that exposing a C interface that takes `void*` is also slightly unpleasant because the user loses type safety -- they can pass in *any* pointer-to-object type with implicit conversion, not just other unrelated handles. I don't think the conversion `Something*` -> `void*` can apply an offset in C or C++, not if done with a static_cast or C-style cast. But even if C++ bindings do pedantically impose some restrictions (that in practice your ABI will say are fine), I don't think that would be worth damaging *other* C interfaces for.

Answer (score 1):

For some people a typedef with "ptr" in the name is more readable and "natural" than declarations using normal pointer syntax.  If you like writing

```
foo* p;
```

instead of

```
foo *p;
```

then the pointer typedef likely appeals to you because it specifically avoids the error of writing

```
foo* p, q;
```

when you meant

```
foo *p, *q;
```

Instead you can write

```
fooptr p, q;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few differences.

Firstly, if you're doing multiple declarations in one line, the following two snippets are equivalent:

```
char *c1, *c2, *c3, *c4;

typedef char * charPtr;
charPtr c1, c2, c3, c4; // I don't need to repeat the unary * everywhere
```

This is useful in part because you might run into semantical issues from trying to do something like:

```
char * c1, c2, c3, c4; // declares one char pointer and three chars
```

Secondly, they can drastically simplify definitions of function pointer types, which are opportunities for almost infinite ugliness and nastiness.

```
float (*someCrazyFunction)(float(*)(), float) = foo; // WTF is this

typedef float (*crazyFunction)(float(*)(), float);
crazyFunction myCrazyFunction = foo; // easier to deal with
```

[Here's an ideone demonstrating all of this behavior.](http://ideone.com/QoAqN)