# Infinite Loop Linked List C

Tags: c, linked-list

I am working on a practice problem to improve my C. Here is the question:

Write a function to sort a linked list of integers as follows:

a) Find the largest value in the list.

b) Delete it from its position and insert it at the head of the list.

c) Starting from what is now the second element, repeat (a) and (b).

d) Starting from what is now the third element, repeat (a) and (b).

Continue until list is sorted.

My sorting function:

```
NodePtr sortList(NodePtr np) {
  NodePtr makeNode(int), head, temp;

  head = temp = np;

  if (np != NULL) {
    // Determine linked list length
    int len = 0;
    while (temp != NULL) {
        len++;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        temp = head;
        int j;
        // Traverse to spot j in linked list
        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            temp = temp -> next;
        }

        // Find largest
        NodePtr largest, prev, prevToLargest;
        largest = prev = prevToLargest = temp;
        while (temp != NULL) {
            if (temp -> num > largest -> num) {
                largest = temp;
                prevToLargest = prev;
            }

            if (temp != prev) prev = prev -> next;
            temp = temp -> next;
        }

        prevToLargest -> next = largest -> next;
        largest -> next = head;
        head = largest;
    }
  }

  return head;
}
```

Using the debugger I have discovered that my list is sorted but it is infinite. I believe I have created a circular linked list, but I'm not sure how to fix that.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Please, please don’t put spaces before and after `->`. This makes your code hard to read and is discouraged nearly everywhere.

Comment: All the sections of your code starting with  a comment can (should?) be pulled  out into their own functions. This will make debugging (and writing unit tests) much easier...

Comment: Why do you have to pre-count the list if it's null-terminated? You should be able to use the terminating null to break the for() or while() loop doing the sort without pre-counting. If nothing else it's non-optimal inefficient code by adding an extra unnecessary loop through the list.

Comment: The comment says "traverse to spot `j` in the list", but you're really traversing to spot `i` in the list and saving that position in `j`.  It's important to name things correctly and specify problems accurately or you get maintenance issues. Also, @idmean is absolutely correct, don't put spaces around `->`

Comment: Think about what happens when there is only one element left in the unsorted part of the list. Then `temp->num > largest->num` will be false (since `temp` and `largest` point to the same node). `temp` and `prev` are also the same node, so the second `if` inside your `while` will not be entered either.  Follow the code to the end and you'll see that the end of the sorted part of the list never gets its `->next` set to `NULL`.

Comment: This is about 3X the code that should be needed for your basic-basic O(N^2) linked list sort. A single pointer-to-pointer eliminates a *ton* of this ([see it live here](http://ideone.com/Dm9wJQ)). And unless there are *very* specific conditions to do otherwise, [hiding pointer types in `typedef` aliases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465976/what-is-the-right-way-to-typedef-a-type-and-the-same-types-pointer) should be avoided. Embrace your C emersion and hug an asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things. First when asking people to debug code try to include line numbers it makes it easier for us to reference the issues. Ok now for actual issues.

1. `if (temp != prev) prev = prev -> next;` on that line of code just have it say prev = temp, rather than prev -> next since temp is always the next one, it's not too big of an issue but I think it makes it easier to follow along.
2. Ok so you insert largest before head by making `largest->next = head`. But what about the index before the spot you inserted that is still pointing to head rather than largest, so you have a broken link in your linked list. *** I am talking about the code after `prevToLargest -> next = largest -> next;`near the end.
3. When you return head, head been moved multiple times. So with your code by the time you iterate through the entire list head is moved to the last element in the list, since you have `head = largest;` and the last largest element is going to be the smallest element which is at the end of the list. So before returning head try pointing it back to the first element in the list.

See if that might fix your issue. There might be more bugs but these are the ones that stood out to me.