# How to correctly iterate over linked list on function call

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Considering this linked list definition:

```
typedef struct lligada{
    int value;
    struct lligada *prox;
}*LInt;

void newInteger(LInt l, int value){
    LInt p = l;
    LInt node = (LInt)malloc(sizeof(struct lligada));
    node->value = value;
    node->prox = NULL;
    while (p->prox) p = p->prox;
    p->prox = node; 
}
```

Is that `p` auxiliary pointer necessary / good practice? Or can I iterate through `LInt l` directly?

Comment: Assuming you haven't actually *tried* yet for whatever reason, yes, you can use `l` to iterate. Unrelated: [Avoid hiding pointer types in type aliases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465976/what-is-the-right-way-to-typedef-a-type-and-the-same-types-pointer). There are really only two concrete reasons to do so (1) A function pointer callback type, and (2) an opaque library handle type, *neither* of which seeming a good fit here. If there is a pointer involved, C programmers *want* to see the asterisks; believe me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `p`; since C passes argument by value, `l` only contains a copy of the value of the original argument, so changes to `l` have no effect outside of the function.  Note that this is different from changing what `l` points to, which *can* have an effect outside the function, as would changing what `p` points to.

Answer (score 0):

In general the function is invalid because the list can be empty and inside the function there is changed local variable `l` that will be destroyed after exiting the function because function parameters are its local variables. Thus an empty list will not be changed.

Also it is not clear why you are trying to add a new node to the tail of a singly-sided list.

In any case the function can look for example like this

```
void newInteger( LInt *l, int value )
{
    LInt node = malloc( sizeof( *LInt ) );

    if ( node != NULL )
    {
        node->value = value;
        node->prox = NULL;

        while ( *l != NULL ) l = &( *l )->prox;

        *l = node;
    }
}
```

Comment: "there is changed local variable l" - *where* is `l` assigned in the OP's posted code ? For all we know the OP is using a head-sentinal ( I wouldn't, doesn't look like you would either, but maybe they are).

Comment: @WhozCraig It tries this indirectly using variable p. But in any case this approach is wrong.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I got segmentation fault on  `while ( *l != NULL ) l = &( *l )->prox;`

Comment: My main: 
    `int i;
    LInt l;
    LInt *p = &l;
    for(i = 2; i < 10; i++) newInteger(p,i);`

Comment: @JohnBauer You need to initialize LInt l with NULL. For example LInt l = NULL;

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the local variable `l`. It is already a copy (most likely allocated on the stack) of the pointer that was sent to the function. Changing it won't affect the original pointer.

To answer the questions:

- It's not necessary.
- I can't see a reason for it to be good practice.

PS - Maybe you want some error checking for null pointers on that function.