# Simple C code illustrated in class doesn't work (typedef related)

Tags: c, struct, typedef

The following piece of code does not compile in Eclipse:

```
typedef int Data;
typedef struct node* Node;
typedef struct node {
    Data data;
    Node next;
};

int main() {
    Node n = newNode();
    return 0;
}

Node newNode() {
    Node newNod;
    newNod = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(!newNod){
        return NULL;
        printf("\naa");
    }
    newNod->data = 3;
    return newNod;
}
```

The one error displayed on compile time is

```
error: conflicting types for 'newNode'* (line with newNode() method declaration "Node newNode() {").
```

I'm clueless. What's wrong?

Comment: "method declaration" ? Sounds like you are using a C++ compiler. Anyway, it doesn't like the name `newNode` is used for both a function name and the variable name.

Comment: @EugeneSh. its being used as a function name, but no variable has that name...

Comment: @CavanPage Right... Misread it.

Comment: What compiler and options are you using?

Comment: @AnthonySottilen Yes - of course.

Comment: `typedef struct node* Node;` avoid hiding stars in typedefs.

Comment: See [What is the right way to typedef a type and the same type's pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3465990/2410359)  Usually hiding a pointer in a `typedef` in an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the definition of `newNode` above `main` [or add a forward declaration of `newNode` above `main`].

In your code, when the compiler sees the call to `newNode` in `main`, it is using an implicit declaration. When the actual definition is encountered, it doesn't match that

Comment: That did remove the compile issue, however the function still doesn't do anything, and also stops the program without throwing an error somehow. I have 'printf' statements all over the program, so I can tell that the program works until the beginning of the newNode() method. (if I put printf in the first line of the method, it doesn't trigger)

Comment: @SergeyBrin Why is there a `printf()` after `return NULL`? What do you want the code to do?

Comment: Oh, never mind, the print stream was messed up... All good now

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
typedef struct node {
    Data data;
    Node next;
};
```

is not correct. The `typedef` requires a name for the type like you did in `typedef struct node* Node;`.
Since you only want to define `struct node` without a typedef, you should remove the word `typedef` in this statement:

```
struct node {
    Data data;
    Node next;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an ancient idea, prior to the c language being standardized where a function that has been called but not yet declared, is **implicitly declared**. In such declaration the return value would be `int` by default.

After the implicit declaration, comes the definition so the compiler is confused.

There are 2 solutions to this,

1. Delcare the function before `main()`, i.e. add

   ```
   Node newNode();
   ```

   before `main()`.
2. Move the entire `newNode()` definition before `main()`.

Now that we've addressed the problem, please note that `typedef`ing a pointer is a bad idea. It's not immediately clear from the code that variables of such type are really pointers. And since there's a very important difference whether they are pointers or not, you should make it as clear as possible.