# Linked list in a class is not removing an element

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int x;
    Node* next = nullptr;
};

typedef Node* nodeptr;

class L
{
    private: 
        nodeptr head = nullptr;
        int lengthCount = 0;
    public: 
        void add(const int data);
        void print();
        void find(const int data);
        void pop(const int data);
        void listSize();
};

void L:: listSize()
{
    cout << "The size of the link list is:  " << lengthCount << endl;
}

void L::add(const int data)
{
    lengthCount += 1;
    Node* newNode = new Node; 
    newNode->x = data;  
    
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        head = newNode; 
    }
    else
    {
        nodeptr temp = head;
        while(temp->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

void L::pop(const int data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
    }   
    else if(head->x == data)
    {
        head = head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeptr temp = head->next; 

        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            if(temp-> x != data)
            {
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else
            { 
                if(temp->next != nullptr)
                {   
                    temp = temp->next;
                }
                else
                {
                    temp->next = nullptr;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

void L::find(const int data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
    }
    else 
    {
        nodeptr temp = head;
        
        for(temp; temp != nullptr; temp = temp->next)
        {
            if(temp->x == data)
            {
                cout << "Found" << endl;
                break;
            }
            if(temp->next == nullptr)
                cout << "Not Found" << endl;    
        }
    }
}

void L::print()
{
    nodeptr temp = head;
    string line(20,'-');
    cout << "Print list" << endl;
    cout << line << endl;
    while(temp != nullptr)
    {
        cout << temp->x << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << line << endl;
}

int main()
{
    vector <int> val;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        val.push_back(5*i);
    cout << "Printing list" << endl;
    for(auto i : val)
            cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
    L listObj;
    cout << "Adding list" << endl;
    for(auto i : val)
        listObj.add(i);
    listObj.print();
    listObj.listSize();
    listObj.find(15);
    listObj.print();
    cout << "popping 10" << endl;
    listObj.pop(10);
    listObj.print();
}
```

The problem that I am having is, I am not able to modify the actually memory of a linked list while using a class.

Im not sure what did I do wrong.

If adding works, i would say the idea of removing a value should work as well.

the remove function is called pop.
the pop function is not removing the value 10, so i am not sure why.

If it is a function that is not in a class, i would say i need to pass a head pointer with & operator then i can actually modify the value.

Please let me know where did I do wrong.

Thanks

Comment: `temp = temp->next;` This doesn't modify the `next` member of a node, but only the variable `temp`.

Comment: `typedef Node* nodeptr;` will eventually cause you problems. It's also longer to type than `Node*` You might want to read through https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3465976/what-is-the-right-way-to-typedef-a-type-and-the-same-types-pointer

Comment: And `temp->next = nullptr;` will basically truncate the list. You need to do something like `nodeBeforeTemp->next = temp->next`. Btw, don't forget the `delete`, you are leaking memory.

Comment: Side note: Your list implementation (if you weren't just experimenting and there wasn't already `std::forward_list`) would likely be added to some library for later re-use in other projects –  but in this case IO within list modifiers is undesirable as some user might have other requirements (e. g. different output format or localised texts or different output channel, e. g. via GUI). So better just inform the caller by return value about some error (e. g. boolean if success/failure is enough, enum for different error conditions, …) – if not modifying now, at least keep in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your pop method is not correct, You also have to link the current node with the previous next. It should be like this

```
void L::pop(const int data)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
    }   
    else if(head->x == data)
    {
        nodeptr temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    else
    {
        nodeptr temp = head->next; 
        nodeptr prev = head;

        while(temp != nullptr)
        {
            if(temp-> x != data)
            {
                prev = temp;
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            else
            {
                if(temp->next != nullptr)
                {   
                    prev -> next = temp -> next;
                    delete temp;
                }
                else
                {
                    delete temp;
                    prev -> next = nullptr;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you `delete`ing the node (memory leak)???

Comment: You forgot the head case; there's no need to differentiate between `temp->next` being `nullptr`; `prev->next = temp->next` is fine even if the successor *is* `nullptr`. Note that `delete` is not a function in C++, it's a *keyword*. Usage with parentheses is at least very uncommon if not bad style.

Comment: Thanks, Yes you are right but I don't want to change the user code too much.

Comment: Then I'd rather comment that change in the code (`// note that ...`). It helps the question author to write better code. In any case you could have written the `delete` part outside of the if/else (code duplication!) as it hasn't been there before anyway. I would avoid, too, usage of the `nodeptr` typedef, as it is bad style anyway, see comment to question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the "previous" node of the linked list somehow. There's many ways to do it, but the clearest might be:

```
void L::pop(const int data) {
    if(head == nullptr) {
        cout << "Empty List" << endl;
        return;
    }   
    if(head->x == data) {
        node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
        return;
    }
    int *prev = head;
    int *temp = head->next;
    while (temp != null) {
        if (temp->x != data) {
            prev = prev->next;
            temp = temp->next;
        } else { 
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua: Thanks. But also feel free to just edit the answer in the future.

Comment: @BillLynch yes actually i have figure out another way of doing it. set temp = head. since if head-->x == data, is checking the first node if thats what we want, so we pretty much can use temp->next->x to check if thats what we want. If the next node data is what we want we just set temp->next = temp->next->next

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers given already there's a variant without having to track the previous element all the time:

```
for(Node* tmp = head; tmp->next; tmp = tmp->next;)
{
    if(tmp->next->x == data)
    {
        // OK, one intermediate pointer we need anyway, but we need it
        // only once
        Node* del = tmp->next;
        tmp->next = tmp->next->next;
        delete del;
        break;
    }
}
```

The `for` loop as a little bonus is a bit more compact, but that's just a matter of personal taste.

Comment: im wondering, does function that is inside a class acts like the same thing as a individual function that is not associated with a class? like if i created a temp pointer inside a class, inside a function, do i have to delete it after using it?

Comment: @JeffreyStewart Free functions and member functions behave identically – apart from the associated object of a member function being mapped to the `this` pointer (`o.f()` -> inside `f` the specific instance `o` is available via `this` pointer). But that's totally unrelated to memory management.

Comment: @JeffreyStewart At very first: You do *not* delete pointers, you delete the *objects* pointed to! It doesn't matter from where the object is pointed to: locally from within a function, member variable, global one – even from all of at the same time is possible – as soon as you do not need the object any more, you delete it. And you need to make sure it is deleted not more than once, no matter how many pointers might keep track of. Once deleted, all pointers pointing to get invalidated, so still reading them before newly assigned results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: i see, actually, i tried to delete the temp object when ever i have created in my function, and i will get seg fault afterwards. I have used temp object for the add function and print function, so i add delete temp at that specific block. So im not sure why. I mean, if you want i can create a new post so you can have a look. but the code will be pretty much the same. Appreciate you help.

Comment: @JeffreyStewart *'whenever I have created'* sounds like you even did so in `add` function, thus as if you don't have a clear image about lifetime of your objects... Be aware that pointer variables don't store the concrete object, but only keep the address of some object in memory. Assigning one pointer to another does not copy the object, only its address. So think of well: When do you still need an object (in your case: as long as part of the list) and when does it get obsolete (on removing from list – and *then* you delete).

Comment: @JeffreyStewart You might want to draw on paper; each node might be represented by a large square, each pointer (don't forget to keep one inside the node, too!) by a small rectangle. Now you can draw arrows from the pointers to the specific objects. Objects with multiple arrays pointed to are yet needed, one only pointed to by a local variable either need to be assigned to another variable (i. e. draw another pointer) or need to be deleted. A node without an array pointing to is leaking and you cannot retrieve back (sure, on paper, you could, but in C++ *not*).